# On Area51 who gets to vote on closing proposals?

Tags: support, reputation, area-51

There has been [some good discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/485/what-discussion-would-a-vi-site-drain-from-other-stack-sites-that-an-emacs-sit) about the recent Vi proposal on Area51. At least 3 Vi/Vim proposals (including the most recent one) got closed. It is not clear to me who makes the decisions to close the proposals.

The [FAQ](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) talks about how much reputation is need to close/reopen/migrate a question but not nothing is said about closing or reopening a proposal.

Who gets to vote on closing and reopening proposals?

Comment: In addition to Borror0's answer, *after* a proposal is closed you can see the **names** of those who closed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were looking at the wrong FAQ. The FAQ in your question is the FAQ for discuss.area51 whereas your question is about Area51 itself.

The FAQ for area51 can be found [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq). It answers your question:

> Amass enough reputation points and Area 51 will allow you to go beyond simply following and voting on proposals.
>
> **25**     Create example questions
> **50**     Create proposals
> **50**     Vote on example questions
> **50**     Flag offensive
> **50**     Leave comments
> **250**     Vote to close or reopen your proposals
> **1000**     Edit other people's posts (proposals and questions)
> **2000**     Vote to close or reopen any proposal
> **10000**    Delete questions and closed proposals, access to moderation tools